Fubini's Theorem: $\int_{2}^x (\int_2^t \frac{du}{log(u)})\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}dt = \int_{2}^x \int_u^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}\cdot log(u)}du dt=...$
I have
\begin{align}
\int_{2}^{x}\left[\int_{2}^{t}
\frac{{\rm d}u}{\log\left(u\right)}\right]\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\,{\rm d}t  & =
\int_{2}^{x}\int_{u}^{x}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}\,\log\left(u\right)}\,{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}t
\\[2mm] & =\int_{2}^{x}\frac{1}{\log\left(u\right)}\left(\int_{u}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}{\rm d}t\right){\rm d}u
\end{align}
because "$2<u<t<x$''.
My friends told me that they applied Fubini. But I do not know HOW. I do not see the equalities.

Fubini's Theorem tells you, under proper condition, your integration in area of $A\subset T\times U$ can be done by iterated integral, that is
$$
\iint_{T\times U} f(t)g(u)\,\mathrm{d}(t,u) = \int_{T} f(t)\left(\int_{U} g(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\right)\mathrm{d}t = \int_{U} g(u)\left(\int_{T} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)\mathrm{d}u
$$
But for specific $A$, you should know how to describe $A$ in your product space $T\times U$, as an example, like your question, $A=\{2<u<t<x\}$ is this triangle below

For the first iterated integral in $A$
$$\int_{T} f(t)\left(\int_{U} g(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\right)\mathrm{d}t$$
whose inner integral is a profile of $t$, shown in $\color{red}{red}$ stripe, $u$ should be ranged from $(2,t)$, that is
$$\iint_{A} f(t)g(u)\,\mathrm{d}(t,u) = \int_{2}^{x} f(t)\left(\int_{2}^{t} g(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\right)\mathrm{d}t$$
As well for the second one in $A$
$$
\int_{U} g(u)\left(\int_{T} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)\mathrm{d}u
$$
whose inner integral is a profile of $u$, shown in $\color{blue}{blue}$ stripe, $t$ should be ranged from $(u,x)$, that is
$$
\iint_{A} f(t)g(u)\,\mathrm{d}(t,u) = \int_{2}^{x} g(u)\left(\int_{u}^{x} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)\mathrm{d}u
$$
